# Messages not being received by ADM client

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm trying to send SNS messages to a Firephone and while I seem to be sending the messages (to somewhere), nothing appears to be getting through to my firephone.

I was able to use the code in the documentation to create the KindleMobilePushApp, was able to generate a RegistrationID, I created the security profile for the test app, etc.  I'm assuming that I must have done something right if I'm getting a registration ID.

Then I tried to send a message to the phone, using the Kindle demo app to receive the message but nothing seems to come through, the "onMessage" method of ADMHandler is never called.

I tried to send message both via the AWS SNS console, and through the java app provided in the documentation (sns.samples.mobilepush),  the Java app seems to be publishing something, but once again, its not coming through to my firephone, or at least not being received by my Receiver class.

I've never used SNS before, so I'm ot sure where the problem is coming form, whether I'm not sending to the right endpoint, or the somehow my app isn't getting the messages its supposed to be getting.  CloudWatch is reporting same number for "messages published" and "messages failed" but really no clue what's happening to the message.

Any thoughts where I should be looking?  Below my manifest, and publish results from the java sender program.

```
<!-- Copyright 2013 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.  -->
<!-- Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"). You may not use this file except in compliance with the License. A copy of the License is located at -->
<!--     http://aws.amazon.com/apache2.0/ -->
<!-- or in the "license" file accompanying this file. This file is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License. -->

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:amazon="http://schemas.amazon.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.grapevine.snstest"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

   <!-- This permission ensures that no other application can intercept your ADM messages. It
   should have the form packagename.permission.RECIEVE_ADM_MESSAGE where packagename is the
   name defined in the "package" property of the manifest tag. --> 
    <permission android:name="com.grapevine.snstest.permission.RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <!-- Required permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.grapevine.snstest.permission.RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.permission.RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"        
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-permission android:name="com.grapevine.snstest.permission.RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.grapevine.snstest.KindleMobilePushApp"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >
            <uses-permission android:name="com.grapevine.snstest.permission.RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Your application's API Key -->
        <!--<meta-data android:name="AmazonAPIKey" android:value="@string/api_key"/>-->

        <!--  Declare your ADMMessageHandlerBase implementation as a service -->
        <service android:name="com.grapevine.snstest.ADMMessageHandler"
            android:exported="false" />

        <!-- You must explicitly enable ADM. You must also declare whether your application will run with or without ADM.
        If you specify android:required="false", your app must degrade gracefully when ADM is unavailable. -->
        <amazon:enable-feature android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging" 
            android:required="true" />

        <receiver android:name="com.grapevine.snstest.ADMMessageHandler$MessageAlertReceiver"
                  android:permission="com.amazon.device.messaging.permission.SEND">
            <uses-permission android:name="com.grapevine.snstest.permission.RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE" />
            <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.intent.REGISTRATION" /> 
               <action android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.intent.RECEIVE" /> 
               <category android:name="com.grapevine.snstest"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>       
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here's the output when I use the MobilePushApp sample program:

```
===========================================

Getting Started with Amazon SNS
===========================================

{PlatformApplicationArn: arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:308914227153:app/ADM/SNSTest}
{EndpointArn: arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:3089xxx53:endpoint/ADM/SNSTest/66xxxf-1f06-3xx1-b887-fxxxxbe19}
{Message Body: {"ADM":"{\"data\":{\"message\":\"Hello World! \"},\"expiresAfter\":1000,\"consolidationKey\":\"Welcome\"}"}}
{Message Attributes:}
Published! 
{MessageId=90f09248-e65b-5713-a6da-debb8e5afcef}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoops, this didn't work because SNS messaging wasn't enabled on the App in the developer portal.